# Como ejecutar funcion en java solo una vez?

Tags: java

Hola quisiera saber como en java puedo ejecutar un método solo una vez(la primera vez que abra el programa), y luego independientemente de todas las veces que decida abrirlo no se vuelva a ejecutar. Espero que se entienda. Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La manera que considero seria mas viable para que pudieras hacer esto seria que la función verificara la existencia de un archivo y en caso de que este no existiera ejecutara la función y lo creara. Esto haría que al momento de la primera ejecución se ejecutaría el código para recabar y verificar la información que requieras, misma que posteriormente se almacenaría en un archivo para que pueda ser utilizada por el programa a partir de la segunda ejecución.

Comment: Me gusta esa idea, me podrías poner un ejemplo de como crearlo y luego verificar su existencia? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Intuyo que vas por el mismo camino :

[Como guardar una variable persistente en java aunque cierre el programa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/170932/como-guardar-una-variable-persistente-en-java-aunque-cierre-el-programa)

Comprueba que existe el fichero, si existe, coge los datos , comprueba y en función de eso , ejecuta tu función como bien te dijeron arriba.
Sino existe crea el fichero...

Para guardar una variable persistentemente usa un fichero.

Para crear ficheros.

http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Lectura_y_Escritura_de_Ficheros_en_Java

Algoritmos de resumen de los que te hablé:

http://marxs7.blogspot.com/2013/07/funciones-de-resumen-md5-y-sha-en-java.html

Encriptación:

https://gist.github.com/arturotena/9235042

Encontrarás miles de págs ... no confundas los algoritmos de resumen con la encriptación, por último, pon un código para ayudarte, aquí nadie te hará el trabajo.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si sólo quieres que la función se ejecute una sóla vez al abrir el programa, se me ocurre lo siguiente:

1. Crear una variable estática booleana por ejemplo dentro de la clase en la que está definida la función e inicializada a true ( por ejemplo).
2. Dentro de la función, meter el código de ésta en un if, y la condición para entrar en el if es 'variable = true'.
3. Una vez dentro del if, tras ejecutar el código de la función, setear a false la variable booleana, de modo que las sucesivas veces que se llame a la función, al comprobar que el valor es false, no entrará en el if y no ejecutará nada.

Sería algo así:

```
    Class A {
     private static boolean variableBooleana = true;

      public void tuFuncion(...) {
        if (variableBooleana == true) {
          
          variableBooleana = false;
        }
      }
    }
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Hola, has entendido mal el problema del OP. Quiere que solo se ejecute una vez incluso cerrando el programa. Tu solución no cumple esto último.

Comment: Correcto, no leí bien la última frase.

Answer (score 0):

Yo también he tenido el mismo problema no hace mucho pero lo mejor para guardar una variable es creando un archivo y verificándolo cada vez que inicias el programa.

Para escribir en el archivo:

```
void escribir(variable){
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("nombrearchivo.txt");
        fw.write(variable)

        fw.close(); //Cerramos el FileWriter para que se guarden los cambios
                }
```

// Para leer el archivo

```
        String leer(){

        // Abres el archivo
        BufferedReader archivo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("nombrearchivo.txt"));

        return archivo.readLine() // Devuelves el valor que se guarda en el archivo


archivo.close();
    }
```