# Como guardar una variable persistente en java aunque cierre el programa

Tags: java

Como guardar el valor de una variable en java para que luego que el programa cierre y vuelva a abrirse la variable conserve su valor? Es que tengo un programa en java que necesito que ejecute unas funciones x solo una sola vez, mi plan es crear una variable booleana persistente la cual tome true la primera vez que corra el programa. Luego solo tengo que verificar su valor, si es true no ejecuto las funciones x y si es false si. Espero explicarme bien. Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Utilizas algún motor de base de datos? No soy experto en Java ni mucho menos, pero asumo que la solución va por aquel lado, otra opción podría ser escribirlo en un documento de texto, pero con un mayor grado de inseguridad

Comment: Si, uso Postgresql, pero creo que crear una BD solo para almacenar una variable no es muy recomendable, debe haber otra forma de conocer si ya se inició antes el programa. Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Puedes intentar usar la clase [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), que permite añadir pares cadena-valor y serializarlos.

Comment: si no vas a guardar datos sensibles como pueden ser pass o cuentas lo puedes guardar en un fichero binario por ejemplo, ahí tendrás el valor al abrir el programa.

Comment: Usa un fichero de texto plano y leelo y grabalo.

Comment: Un fichero como bien te dicen, si te preocupa la integridad del fichero, puedes usar un algoritmo de resumen para cerciorarte que una persona ajena no lo ha modificado y encriptando el contenido para que nadie lea el contenido.

Comment: çEl concepto se denomina **persistencia**, y la lista de opciones es muuuy larga: BD, serialización java, serialización XML, serialización Properties, tu propio formato de serialización, facilidades propias del SO, WS, etc.

Comment: Dando vueltas por StackOverflow en Inglés di con [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784657/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-user-settings-in-java-application), que asumo que es exactamente lo que necesitas

Answer (score 2):

Una manera muy sencilla de hacerlo es utilizando las preferencias de Java. Esta es una manera muy sencilla de almacenar valores sin tener que preocuparse de crear un archivo de texto o de crear una base datos, que al final terminarían siendo formas muy laboriosas cuando lo que se quiere es almacenar un solo valor de tipo booleano.

El uso de las preferencias es muy sencillo, al crear la instancia de esta, le pasas como clave el nombre del paquete de la clase donde la implementas, o bien, puede ser el .class de la clase. Esta clave es la que siempre utilizaras para acceder a esta preferencia.

```
// Accede a las preferencias del usuario utilizando el paquete de la clase.
Preferences preferences = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(Preferencias.class);

// Almacenas las preferencias en pares clave valor.
preferences.putBoolean("verdadero", true);

// Obtienen las preferencias. En caso de que la preferencia
// no exista, retorna el valor por defecto. El valor por
// defecto de la preferencia es el que se le pasa como
// segundo parametro.
boolean verdadero = preferences.getBoolean("verdadero", false);

System.out.println(verdadero); // Imprime true
```

> Si antes has trabajado con Android notaras que hay mucha similitud entre estas preferencias y las preferencias de Android.

Te dejo el enlace oficial de la documentación Java.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html